# Connect Logitech MX900 keyboard

Tags: linux-mint, keyboard, bluetooth

My Logitech hardware Bluetooth hub suddenly stopped working, so I am trying to connect the Logitech MX900 Mouse and Keyboard units directly to my Samsung 900X laptop runnning Linux Mint 17.1 Rebecca.

I could connect the mouse through the Blueman graphical manager, and it works. But the keyboard, although it says it connects successfully, does not.

Googling the problem hasn't brought me much, other than this:

```
$ sudo hcitool -ihci0 info 00:07:61:23:27:CD
Requesting information ...
BD Address:  00:07:61:23:27:CD
Device Name: Logitech MX900 Mouse
LMP Version: 1.2 (0x2) LMP Subversion: 0x545
Manufacturer: Cambridge Silicon Radio (10)
Features: 0xfc 0xff 0x0f 0x00 0x08 0x08 0x00 0x00
    <encryption> <slot offset> <timing accuracy> <role switch> 
    <hold mode> <sniff mode> <park state> <RSSI> <channel quality> 
    <SCO link> <HV2 packets> <HV3 packets> <u-law log> <A-law log> 
    <CVSD> <paging scheme> <power control> <transparent SCO> 
    <AFH cap. slave> <AFH cap. master> 
$ sudo hcitool -ihci0 cc 00:07:61:23:27:CD 
$ hcitool conn
Connections:
    > ACL 00:07:61:23:37:FA handle 34 state 1 lm MASTER
```

The *hcitool cc* command doesn't output anything at all, but the keyboard is still not working, and doesn't appear in the connection list (that's the mouse listed above).

Are there any alternate tools I could try, that at least could give me a bit more information?